# Java Interface: Inheriting, Overriding, and Overloading Methods

Tags: java, interface, overriding, overloading

In "THE Java™ Programming Language, Fourth Edition" By Ken Arnold, James Gosling, David Holmes, its mentioned that:

**paragraph: (4.3.2)**
*"Similarly, if an interface inherits more than one method with the same signature, or if a class implements different interfaces containing a method with the same signature, there is only one such method. The implementation of this method is ultimately defined by the class implementing the interfaces, and there is no ambiguity there. If the methods have the same signature but different return types, then one of the return types must be a subtype of all the others, otherwise a compile-time error occurs. The implementation must define a method that returns that common subtype."*

**Can anybody give me some example code that justifies the points of above paragraph ?**

I tried to write the code and test what is mentioned but I am getting compile-time error
the sub-interface hides the base interface method so can only implement sub-interface method.

Thanks in advance.
-Arun

Comment: post your code and your compiler errors dude... at least give us something to (a) reproduce the issue; and (b) go from there.

Comment: Everyone I am really sorry - I was trying to test what was mentioned in the above mentioned para using j2sdk1.4.2_08 - I didn't realize that the book is written for JDK1.5
So that means if you compile the code snippet by "Daniel Schneller" using JDK1.4 you will get a "ImplementationOfAandB.java:17: methodB() in ImplementationOfAandB cannot implement methodB() in InterfaceA; attempting to use incompatible return type" compilation error whereas with JDK1.5 it just runs fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following two interfaces `methodA()` is identically defined in terms of parameters (none) and return type (int). The implementation class at the bottom defines a single method with this exact signature. As it complies to both interfaces, you get no problem there - any calls made via a reference of type InterfaceA or InterfaceB will be dispatched to this implementation.

The second `methodB()` is defined as returning any subtype of `Number` (or `Number` itself) in `InterfaceA`. `InterfaceB` defines `methodB()` as returning an `Integer` which is a subtype of `Number`. The implementation class actually implements the method with `Integer`, thus complying to the contract of both `InterfaceA` and `InterfaceB`. No problem here either.
The commented out case of `methodB()` being implemented as returning a `Double` however would not work: While it would satisfy the contract of `InterfaceA`, it would conflict with `InterfaceB` (which demands an `Integer`).

If `InterfaceA` and `InterfaceB` were also specifying (different) contracts for a `methodC()` (commented out in the example) this would be contradictory and create a compiler error. Implementing both signatures (differing only in return type) is not allowed in Java.

The above rules would also hold true if were to add any parameters to the methods. For simplicity I kept this out of the example.

```
public interface InterfaceA {
    public int methodA();
    public Number methodB();
    // public int methodC(); // conflicting return type
}

public interface InterfaceB {
    public int methodA();
    public Integer methodB();
    // public String methodC(); // conflicting return type
}

public class ImplementationOfAandB implements InterfaceA, InterfaceB {
    public int methodA() {
        return 0;
    }
    public Integer methodB() {
        return null;
    }
    // This would NOT work:
    // public Double methodB() {
    //     return null;
    // }
}
```

Comment: Everyone I am really sorry - I was trying to test what was mentioned in the above mentioned para using j2sdk1.4.2_08 - I didn't realize that the book is written for JDK1.5
So that means if you compile the code snippet by "Daniel Schneller" using JDK1.4 you will get a "ImplementationOfAandB.java:17: methodB() in ImplementationOfAandB cannot implement methodB() in InterfaceA; attempting to use incompatible return type" compilation error whereas with JDK1.5 it just runs fine.

Answer (score 8):

```
interface A {
    void method();
    Object returnMethod();
}
interface B {
    void method();
    B returnMethod();
}

class Impl implements A,B 
{
    void method() { }
    B returnMethod() { }
}
```

As you can see, `Impl.method()` implements both `A.method()` and `B.method()`, while `Impl.returnMethod()` returns a `B`, which is a child of `Object`, thus fulfilling `A.returnMethod()`'s contract too. Would the latter require a return type that is not a parent of `B.returnMethod()`'s return type that would be a comile error, since no such implementation could exist in `Impl`.

Comment: Is that C#? The question is about Java.

Comment: I don't think it matters which language ;)

Comment: And no, Impl must implement the more specific return type in order to satisfy both interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

```
interface A
{
   void foo();
   //int bar(); <-- conflicts with B.bar() because of different return type
}

interface B
{
   void foo();
   //double bar(); <-- conflicts with A.bar() because of different return type
}

class C implements A, B
{
   void foo() // this implements A.foo() AND B.foo()
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?:

```
interface A {
    Object get();
}
interface B {
    Number get();
}

abstract class MyClass implements A, B {
    // Try to override A.get, but cause a compile error.
    public Object get() { return null; }
}
```

Such a method in MyClass is automatically generated by javac as a synthetic bridge method. You must implement a single method returning a type compatible with all of the implemented/overridden methods (in this case `Number`/`Integer`/`Double`/etc).

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * This is what you have
 */
interface IXR {
        //bla-bla-bla
}

class CXR implements IXR {
        //concrete implementation of bla-bla-bla
}

interface IX {
        public IXR f();
} 

interface IYR {
        //some other bla-bla-bla
}

class CYR implements IYR {
        //concrete implementation of the some other bla-bla-bla
} 

interface IY {
        public IYR f();
}






/**
 * This is what you need to add
 */ 
interface IZR extends IXR, IYR {
        //EMPTY INTERFACE
}

class CZXR extends CXR implements IZR {
        //EMPTY CLASS
} 

class CZYR extends CYR implements IZR {
        //EMPTY CLASS
}

class CZ implements IX, IY
{
        public static boolean someCondition = true;

        public IXR implementationOf_X_f()
        {
                System.out.println("CXR");
                return new CZXR();
        }

        public IYR implementationOf_Y_f()
        {
                System.out.println("CYR");
                return new CZYR();
        }

        public IZR f() {
                if (someCondition) {
                        return (IZR) implementationOf_X_f();
                } else {
                        return (IZR) implementationOf_Y_f();
                }
        }

}






/**
 * This is the usage of the required class
 */
class program 
{ 
        public static void main(String[] x) {
                CZ o = new CZ();
                IZR r = o.f();
                if (CZ.someCondition) {
                        CXR xr = (CXR) r;
                        //bla-bla-bla
                } else {
                        CYR yr = (CYR) r;
                        //bla-bla-bla
                }
        }
} /**
 * This is what you have
 */
interface IXR {
        //bla-bla-bla
}

class CXR implements IXR {
        //concrete implementation of bla-bla-bla
}

interface IX {
        public IXR f();
} 

interface IYR {
        //some other bla-bla-bla
}

class CYR implements IYR {
        //concrete implementation of the some other bla-bla-bla
} 

interface IY {
        public IYR f();
}






/**
 * This is what you need to add
 */ 
interface IZR extends IXR, IYR {
        //EMPTY INTERFACE
}

class CZXR extends CXR implements IZR {
        //EMPTY CLASS
} 

class CZYR extends CYR implements IZR {
        //EMPTY CLASS
}

class CZ implements IX, IY
{
        public static boolean someCondition = true;

        public IXR implementationOf_X_f()
        {
                System.out.println("CXR");
                return new CZXR();
        }

        public IYR implementationOf_Y_f()
        {
                System.out.println("CYR");
                return new CZYR();
        }

        public IZR f() {
                if (someCondition) {
                        return (IZR) implementationOf_X_f();
                } else {
                        return (IZR) implementationOf_Y_f();
                }
        }

}






/**
 * This is the usage of the required class
 */
class program 
{ 
        public static void main(String[] x) {
                CZ o = new CZ();
                IZR r = o.f();
                if (CZ.someCondition) {
                        CXR xr = (CXR) r;
                        //bla-bla-bla
                } else {
                        CYR yr = (CYR) r;
                        //bla-bla-bla
                }
        }
}
```